# How to disconnect a ble device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to disconnect a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device.My code works fine in lollipop and lower versions and connecting again to the BLE device also works fine. However, when I disconnect in nougat it disconnects the BLE device, but connecting again fails and shows the error "app is not responding". This is my code. I am trying to disconnect onBackPressed() method.

```
 public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this);
        adb.setTitle("DISCONNECT");
        adb.setCancelable(true);
        adb.setMessage("Do you want to disconnect");
        adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mBTLE_Service.disconnect();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = adb.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: whats your android version 7.0 or 7.1?

Comment: In android 7.0 if you turn bluetooth off mobile don&amp;#39;t break connection with already connected devices. Yea that's the bug in 7.0. I'm not sure but i think they solved it in 7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `mBTLE_Service.close();`  instead of `mBTLE_Service.disconnect();`

Comment: I also try mBTLE_Service.close(); but it does not work

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your connection code.